# Which tools do you guys use for MD5 brute forcing in Mac OS X?

Tags: mac, md5

I am new to Macs, so I don't know which tool is good for MD5 brute forcing in Mac OS X. Do you have any suggestions?

Comment: Ignoring the potential "bad" reasons you might wish to break hashes, this question is totally [off-topic](http://superuser.com/faq#dontask) as it's "what are your favorite X?".

Comment: @DMA57361 - there are legit reasons for cracking hashes too.. Like when you forget a password you need, or if you're conducting a security audit.. Probably other legit cases too.

Comment: @TheWhile hence my use of the word "potential", it's still the wrong type of question for the site. If they've lost a password, they should be asking how to recover from that problem.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am a big fan of John the Ripper. You can find a custom build for OS X here:

> http://openwall.info/wiki/john/custom-builds#Compiled-for-Mac-OS-X

Comment: +1 John the Ripper seems like the defacto tool for this kind of thing. Hopefully Winthan doesn't mind the command line too much.

Comment: I didn't know there is Mac version of John :) I love it :)

Comment: @Winthan - Indeed.. And if you're not already aware of it, you can get other great common unixy tools through MacPorts. Worth checking out.